# sails.js sails.services and sails.models don't contain my services and methods

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) application I am attempting to turn off the default global variables for services and models like so:

```
sails: true,
services: false,
models: false
```

Just as a style preference, I wanted to explicitly use sails.models.X and sails.services.Y to access models and services.  But when I do this, my models and services are null. If I leave the defaults turned on and access the globals X and Y, all is well.  But the documentation indicates that what I'm attempting should work:

```
/****************************************************************************
  *                                                                           *
  * Expose each of your app's services as global variables (using their       *
  * "globalId"). E.g. a service defined in api/models/NaturalLanguage.js      *
  * would have a globalId of NaturalLanguage by default. **If this is disabled, *
  * you can still access your services via sails.services.***                   *
  *                                                                           *
  ****************************************************************************/
```

Similar verbiage is present for models as well.

I'm not doing anything else out of the ordinary as far as I can tell.  Just using standard generated models and nothing crazy with my services or other config. Should this really work?  This is v 0.11  Thanks!

Comment: I know that when you access directly off of sails.services everything is lower case instead of camel case. That might be your issue, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: @Meeker: Doh!  Yep it was that I was casing it as the global. Would be great if that were documented, perhaps I'll do a pull request on the docs.  If you want to add an answer I'm happy to give you credit.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing about docs. I'll let you at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that when you access directly off of sails.services everything is lower case instead of camel case. That might be your issue, but otherwise it should work.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2869#issuecomment-95794081